# python gtk - How to define the size of gtk.textview?

Tags: python, textview, gtk

I have constructed a Texview like this:

```
#textview
self.fd = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
tableau2.attach(self.fd, 0, 2, 0, 4, xpadding=10, ypadding=5)
self.fd.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

self.textview = gtk.TextView()
self.textview.set_editable(False)
self.textview.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD)
self.textview.set_cursor_visible(True)
self.textview.set_justification(gtk.JUSTIFY_LEFT)
self.buffertexte = self.textview.get_buffer()
self.edition = self.textview.get_editable()
self.iterdebut = self.buffertexte.get_end_iter()
self.buffertexte.set_text("")
self.fd.add(self.textview)
self.fd.show()
self.textview.show()
```

But the height is too little in Unity3D:
[image]

How to modify this size?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `set_size_request` on the textview:

```
self.textview.set_size_request(-1, desired_min_height)
```